# IntelliJ CTRL+H shortkey equivalent in MyEclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I used `IntelliJ` idea for development before.
Now I emigration to `MyEclipse` environement.
In `IntelliJ` idea I used `CTRL+H` shortkey for this class hierarchy.
My question is : Is there equivalent for `CTRL+H` in `MyEclipse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut for class hierarchy in eclipse is <kbd>F4</kbd>. In eclipse it is called type hierarchy.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> you can also browse through your currently defined shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

To see type hierarchy in a toolbox you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or <kbd>F4</kbd> if you want to open Type Hierarchy View.

Answer (score 0):

To see call hierarchy, in eclipse <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.